# How can I extract the x and y values from a coordinate pair?

Tags: list-manipulation

I think the question says it all. I have a coordinate pair, {x,y} and I want to extract x and y for use in further calculations. Can't find anything in the docs about this but it seems like it should be a pretty simple operation.

Comment: [Extract](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
{x,y}[[1]]
{x,y}[[2]]
```

Watch the docs for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetElementsOfLists.html)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to answer provided by @Kay:

One of the alternative ways to extract data would be using `First` and `Last` functions:

**Example:**

```
(*Arbitrary data*)
coord = {76, 2};

(*Process*)
First @ coord
Last @ coord
```

You could also extract the entire set of `x` and `y` values.

**Example :**

```
(*Arbitrary data*)
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 2}]

(*All 'x' values*)
data[[All, 1]]

(*All 'y' values*)
data[[All, 2]]
```

**Reference:**

[@ # % etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
[Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)
[First](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html)
[Last](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html)

**Tutorial:**

[Getting Pieces of Lists](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingPiecesOfLists.html)

Comment: You should perhaps add `{x,y}[[-2]]` and `{x,y}[[-1]]`...

Comment: Yes, this another way to do it

Answer (score 3):

there is another way as well:

```
#1 & @@ {1, 2} (* gives 1 *)
#2 & @@ {1, 2} (* gives 2 *)
```

for multiple coordinates in a list:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 2}]

#1 & @@@ data (* gives all x coordinates *)
#2 & @@@ data (* gives all y coordinates *)
```